# create setter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a setter in JS. But there is something wrong with my code, and this is my code:

```js
class test {
  constructor(str) {
    this.name = str;
  }

  set name(str) {
    this.sayHi();
  }
  sayHi() {
    let temp = this.name;
    console.log(`My name is ${temp}`)
  }
}

let a = new test('bill') //My name is undefined
a.sayHi() //My name is undefined
```

why does it console undefined in this example?how to make it work?

Comment: Because you're not setting anything in the setter.

Comment: `console.log('My name is ' + this.name)`

Answer (score 4):

Your setter needs to store the value somewhere; you'll also need a getter to get the value from that place.

Here's a simple example storing the value in another property:

```js
class Test {
    constructor(str) {
        this._name = str;  // ***
        // (You might use `this.name = str` here, setters are sometimes
        // considered an exception to the "don't call methods in the
        // constructor" rule)
    }

    set name(str) {
        this._name = str;  // ***
    }
    
    get name() {           // ***
        return this._name; // ***
    }                      // ***
    
    sayHi() {
        let temp = this.name;
        console.log(`My name is ${temp}`)
    }
}

let a = new Test('bill')   //My name is undefined
a.sayHi()  //My name is undefined
```

Of course, if you're going to do that, it doesn't make a lot of sense to have a setter, but that's getting a bit afield of the question...

---

Note: I changed the name of your class to `Test` (instead of `test`). The *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is that class names (really constructor function names) are initially-capitalized.

Comment: thank you for your explanation:)  i am new for JavaScript,and i don't know how to use setter and getter in the right way,is there any information for this?

Comment: thank you for your explanation:)  i am new for JavaScript,and i don't know how to use setter and getter in the right way,is there any information for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
class test {
 constructor(str) {
     this.name = str;
 }

 set name(str) {
     this._name = str
 }
 sayHi() {
     let temp = this.name;
     console.log(`My name is ${temp}`)
 }
 get name() {
     return this._name
 }
}
```

Comment: @Li357 Otherwise you'll get infinite recursion

Comment: @dorintufar I didn't see that, my bad